# how to fix add command not found error on putty ssh

Tags: bash, shell, hive, hortonworks-sandbox

I have created a hadoop cluster using hortonworks sanbox VM on windows. For that I am using putty SSH. I want to add a custom jsonserde jar to hive. I am using `add jar` command, but i am getting an error like

> -bash: add: command not found.

This is for putty ssh

```
add jar /usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/hive/lib/json-serde-1.3.7-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
```

I expect this [`jar`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYSCO.png) to be added to specified path.

Answer (score 2):

`ADD JAR` is a Hive command, not shell. Read more here: [HiveResources](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli#LanguageManualCli-HiveResources)

Execute it in the Hive script in the same session before using in the query.

Example:

```
hive> add jar /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/jtds-1.2.jar;
```

Hive prints:

```
Added [/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/jtds-1.2.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/jtds-1.2.jar]
```

Comment: how to confirm if the jar has been added? It is showing that jar is added to the classpath. Where can I see that classpath?

Comment: `list files;` Hive command will show all files added; Do not know how to print classpath from hive.

Comment: @DeepenPatel Hive prints that it was added in the classpath and resources in the distributed cache. Updated the answer with example

Comment: @DeepenPatel Have found how to print classpath from Hive: hive> select java_method('java.lang.System','getProperty','java.class.path'); But it does not print newly added jar in my case, though it works